# A proof about a condition of Riemann integrable functions on my textbook

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals, riemann-integration, partitions-for-integration

I was stuck when proving a theorem in Introduction to real analysis (4th edition).
[image]
I don't know why the author assumed $c=x_{i}=x_{i-1}$. Is it because $x_{i}$ and $x_{i+1}$ are close enough or coincide. But if so, the mesh $\| \dot{\mathcal{P}} \|$ should be zero then there is no need to take that into account. Could anyone explain why this proof did so?

By the way, the definition of partition is below:[image]

Comment: If $c$ is not an endpoint for a given partition $P$ then the Riemann sums of $f$, $g$ are identical. Thus we just need to show that for a given partition $P$, if it contains $c$ as one of the endpoints that nothing "too bad" happens and that it is very similar to a partition not containing $c$ (for which the sums are equal).

Answer (score 3):

The author doesn't assume that $c = x_i =x_{i-1}$. He says that $S(f, \dot{\mathcal P})$ and $S(g, \dot{\mathcal P})$ are equal except if $c$ is one of the endpoint of the tagged partition $\dot{\mathcal P}$. And in the later case he bounds the difference$S(f, \dot{\mathcal P})-S(g, \dot{\mathcal P})$.

Also, I think that the author meant $c=x_i$ **or** $c=x_{i-1}$. $c = x_i = x_{i-1}$ doesn't make sense as the endpoints of a partition are supposed to be distinct.

Comment: I was just about to post an answer, but I leave it as a comment here. The author probably mean that $c = t_{i} = t_{i-1}$ since then there are two terms in the Riemann sum which differ. For clarity the $t$:s are where the function is evaluated in the Riemann sum.